# How can I mock the `Reference.prototype.update` method in `firebase-admin/database` with Jest?

Tags: firebase, jestjs, firebase-admin

I'm trying to spy on the `update` method of Firebase Realtime Database using `firebase-admin`

My code roughly looks like:

```
import admin = require("firebase-admin");
import * as database from "firebase-admin/database";

admin.initializeApp();

const db = database.getDatabase();

... 

function X() { 
   const myRef = db.ref("hello");
   ...
   myRef.update(updates);

}
```

I'd like to spy on these `myRef.update` calls with Jest.

As `firebase-admin` is not modular, I can not simply rewrite the final call to `update(myRef, updates)`.

I could not find any exports of the `database.Reference` class, only the interface. How can I still have something like `jest.spyOn(database.Reference.prototype, "update")`?